# Validating Same Password Input Angular 2/4 - ERROR Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

I'm trying to validate that the password and ConfirmPassword fields are the same in my form, but when I add the validation provided by other posts on SO (aside from changing ControlGroup to FormGroup) I keep getting

ERROR: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

BUT, when I don't validate using the "matchingPassword" group below and just use the Validators.required syntax, it works just fine.

I don't know why it's throwing that error. Has anyone else worked through this? I'm currently building on Angular 4 Distro.

```
constructor(
private accountService: accountService,
fb: FormBuilder,
) {
    this.changePWForm = fb.group({
        'CurrentPassword' : [null, Validators.required],
        'SecurityQuestions' : [null, Validators.required],
        'SecurityQuestionAnswer' : [null, Validators.required],
         'matchingPassword': fb.group({
                'NewPassword' : [null, Validators.compose([Validators.pattern(this.strongPW), Validators.required])],
                'ConfirmPassword' : [{disabled: true}, Validators.required],
            }, {validator: this.equalPasswords})

    })


}

equalPasswords(group: FormGroup){
   //When I use the syntax above, it never makes it here.
    var valid = false;

        for (var name in group.controls) {
            var val = group.controls[name].value


        }

        if (valid) {
            return null;
        }

        return {
            areEqual: true
        };

}
```

Here's My HTML Template

```
 <form [formGroup]="changePWForm" (ngSubmit)="updatePW(changePWForm.value)" *ngIf="securityQuestions">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Current Password:</label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="changePWData.CurrentPassword" [formControl]="changePWForm.controls['CurrentPassword']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>New Password:</label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="changePWData.NewPassword" [formControl]="changePWForm.controls['NewPassword']">
            <small *ngIf="!changePWForm.controls.NewPassword.valid && !changePWForm.controls.NewPassword.pristine">You need a secure password.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" >
            <label>Confirm New Password:</label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="changePWData.ConfirmPassword" [formControl]="changePWForm.controls['ConfirmPassword']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Security Question:</label>
            <select #select type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedSecurityQuestion" [formControl]="changePWForm.controls['SecurityQuestions']" class="select">
                <option *ngFor="let question of securityQuestions" [ngValue]="question">{{question.SecurityQuestionText}}</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Security Question Answer: </label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="securityQuestionAnswer" [formControl]="changePWForm.controls['SecurityQuestionAnswer']">
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="processing">
                    <div class="spinner">
                        <div class="rect1"></div>
                        <div class="rect2"></div>
                        <div class="rect3"></div>
                        <div class="rect4"></div>
                        <div class="rect5"></div>
                    </div>

            </div>
            <button *ngIf="!processing" type="submit" [disabled]="!changePWForm.valid">Change Address</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've a nested `FormGroup` (`matchingPassword`).

So, you must wrap the controls of this *nested* group using a `<div>`, for example.

Wrap your password controls (NewPassword and ConfirmPassword) in a element, like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="changePWForm" ...>    
  ...    
  <div formGroupName="matchingPassword">
    <!-- you can also use [formGroup] if you want -->
    <!-- Put the content of password controls here -->
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides having the problem stated by developer033, that you are missing the `formGroupName`:

```
<div formGroupName="matchingPassword">
  <!-- you can also use [formGroup] if you want -->
  <!-- Put the content of password controls here -->
</div>
```

.. I also didn't really understand the custom validator and it didn't function correctly for me. Also noticed for some reason the validator don't even fire when marking form controls like:

```
[formControl]="changePWForm.controls['NewPassword']"
```

I can't really say why, but I also prefer the more "cleaner" version:

```
formControlName="NewPassword"
```

So changing those would make the custom validator fire.

Then to the custom validator, this is the way I do it. Also notice I've changed `areEqual: true` to `notEqual:true` to better describe what is actually going on, since when we return `null` it means that the passwords match, and if we return something else than `null`, it means that we want to mark that the passwords do not match.

```
equalPasswords = (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} =>{
  const newPassword = control.get('NewPassword');
  const confirmPassword = control.get('ConfirmPassword');

  if (!newPassword || !confirmPassword) {
    return null;
  }

  return newPassword.value === confirmPassword.value ? null : { notEqual: true };
}
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/pMmdrE2ulHpqQmvnv6kg?p=preview)** with a shortened version of your code.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't mentioned the fact of his *function* is incorrect, because I thought it was just an example and he was just trying to fix the *template error* before. And about the *cleaner* version I agree with your statement, however I prefer to create a reference in component file and use like this `[formControl]="myVariableCtrl"` :) it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: Yeah it's a matter of preference therefore I said that I prefer.. :P But yeah, I figured the function was the one OP uses, so I just thought to take care of that at the same time *(read: I was bored )* :D

Comment: @developer033 Aah, forgot to tag you :P